# Error 104: Connection reset by peer in Nginx using Node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx

```html
2016/08/18 18:15:28 [error] 19201#0: *38 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 116.36.170.142, server: , request: "POST /adm/contents/insert HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/adm/contents/insert", host: "cidermics.com", referrer: "http://cidermics.com/adm/contents/insert"
2016/08/18 18:15:28 [error] 19201#0: *38 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 116.36.170.142, server: , request: "POST /adm/contents/insert HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/adm/contents/insert", host: "cidermics.com", referrer: "http://cidermics.com/adm/contents/insert"
```

104: Connection reset by peer

It's an error When I insert some contents in Nginx AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

(But I can insert it in localhost server when I upload same things.)

502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.8.1

The important thing is I can insert it when the short codes in sql server(but sometimes I can't insert even short codes if it include bold tag or color font etc),

But if I insert it when It long codes, It can't upload.

(even It can insert in localhost.)

I think the problem is Nginx or SQL.

I used to have an nginx too large entity error so I put the "client_max_body_size size;".

AWS error logs codes

```html
/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:48:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:83:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:73:12)
    at Protocol.write (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:98:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:531:20)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
    at PoolConnection.query (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:203:25)
    at /var/app/current/routes/model/mysql.js:28:14
    at Ping.onOperationComplete [as _callback] (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:101:5)
    at Ping.Sequence.end (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Ping.Sequence.OkPacket (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:105:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:73:12)
    at Protocol.write (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:98:28)
```

proxy.conf

```html
# Elastic Beanstalk Managed

# Elastic Beanstalk managed configuration file
# Some configuration of nginx can be by placing files in /etc/nginx/conf.d
# using Configuration Files.
# http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html 
# 
# Modifications of nginx.conf can be performed using container_commands to modify the staged version
# located in /tmp/deployment/config/etc#nginx#nginx.conf
 
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

server {
 
 client_max_body_size 3000M;
    listen 80;
    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
        set $hour $4; 
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
 
 

    location / {
     client_max_body_size 3000M;
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;  
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        
       
    }
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 4;
gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
 
    
}
```

Comment: You argue that you're using SQL server but got a MySQL error.  You'r problem likely lies there.  Why are you using MySQL node module to talk to SQL server?  Their parameter syntax (how you add extra parameters into the query) is different.